# MVC Conditional filter Provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a scenario, In my project where I have to handle two modes Internet and Intranet. Now I have to apply the filters based on the Modes, what is the best way to apply the filters based on the modes(conditionally).

One way to do this is to create custom filter provider and register it. but how and when I can check the application mode.

Thanks,
-Babu

Comment: Is it easy to tell by the ip what network the user is from either the intranet or internet, ie does the  intranet ip's start with 10, 172, or 192 ?

Comment: ya that's correct but the question is related to applying the conditional filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you're using [Phil Haacked's Conditional Filter Provider](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/24/conditional-filters.aspx/):

```
public class ConditionalFilterProvider : IFilterProvider {
  private readonly 
    IEnumerable<Func<ControllerContext, ActionDescriptor, object>> _conditions;

  public ConditionalFilterProvider(
    IEnumerable<Func<ControllerContext, ActionDescriptor, object>> conditions)
  {
      _conditions = conditions;
  }

  public IEnumerable<Filter> GetFilters(
      ControllerContext controllerContext, 
      ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) {
    return from condition in _conditions
           select condition(controllerContext, actionDescriptor) into filter
           where filter != null
           select new Filter(filter, FilterScope.Global, null);
  }
}
```

And that you have two custom ActionFilterAttribute, called IntranetAttribute and InternetAttribute. Let's also say that all Intranet requests will come from either IP address: 10.122.122.12 or 10.122.122.13.

You can configure the Conditional Provider in Application_Start like this:

```
    private void ConfigureModeAttribute()
    {
        //Configure a conditional filter
        string[] intranetIPs = { "10.122.122.12", "10.122.122.13" };
        IEnumerable<Func<ControllerContext, ActionDescriptor, object>> conditions =
            new Func<ControllerContext, ActionDescriptor, object>[] {
                    ( c, a ) => intranetIPs.Contains(c.HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress) ?
                    new IntranetAttribute() : new InternetAttribute() 
            };

        var provider = new ConditionalFilterProvider(conditions);

        // This line adds the filter we created above
        FilterProviders.Providers.Add(provider);
    }
```

Hope it will help you!

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please note that you should post the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.

Comment: Ok, @bluefeet, I've fleshed it out.