# mvc 5 'conditional filter'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-filters

I have an MVC site and I want to apply some custom logic such that whenever a user logs in or authentication is confirmed, if their mobile number is not verified, i redirect them to the verification page.
I would like this check to only 'occur' wherever authentication is needed on the site.
I have tried registering as a global filter but then this check is called every single time any view/action is done. (I have logic in there that can detect whether or not theyre authenticated). I feel like this is a bit of an unnessary overhead and inefficiency...there are lots of controller actions decorated with the [Authorize] attribute and wouldnt want to add another custom attribute to each to get this working nor do i want to write my own custom [Authorize] provider. Are there any options??
Again, what I would like to happen is whenever a user is authenticated,I would like my logic for phone number verification to occur
Thanks!

Comment: These might help - http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/25/conditional-filters.aspx/ , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19632655/mvc-conditional-filter-provider

Comment: So why not just add your check to the login action?

Comment: I can add it to the login action, problem is that you could log in (i.e be authenticated) and then be directed to the page to verify the number..but you could for example, just navigate away or change the url and you will be still authenticated etc on the site. Hence I was thinking if I could hook into the event when it checks if a user is authenticated

Comment: Your question says "I wouldnt want to add another custom attribute to each to get this working nor do i want to write my own custom [Authorize] provider" So I read that to mean you want to put the code one place? The check against IsAuthenticated can happen anywhere since it's only checking the auth cookie which is sent with the request. On the other hand you've also said you don't want to run this check everywhere, like putting the code in base controller. Thesimplest way is to not authenticate the user unless they have supplied mobile, you'd override that in the Login action.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for the information. Clarifies a few things. I have created an a class that implements the IAuthenticationFilter interface and noticed that even on a static page, the "OnAuthenticationChallenge" is called about every 60seconds (I assume thats the default value).Its also called whenever you navigate elsewhere so looks like I might just implement it there, as you said too, it can happen anytime too the auth cookie is 'checked'. Will give it a go and see! Just need to figure how to instantiate the UserManager (using OWIN) :) Thanks